# how to navigate from one scene to another scene in react native router flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react native router flux in my react native application.

I created some scenes in Route.

```js
<Router>
            <Scene key="root" hideNavBar={true} navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#81b71a' }}>
                <Scene key="auth">
                    <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} title="Please Login" />
                </Scene>
                <Scene key="main" navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#8fff1f' }}>
                    <Scene
                        key="mainScene1" 
                        component={EmployeeList} 
                        title="MainScene1"
                    />
                    <Scene key="mainScene2" component={EmployeeCreate} title="MainScene1" />
                    <Scene key="MainScene3" component={EmployeeEdit} title="Edit Employee" />
                </Scene>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
```

I want to navigate from **mainScene3** to **mainScene1** but getting error "Error: There is no route defined for key mainScene1. Must be one of: 'auth','main'  "

How to tackle this issue? These two scene are in the same bucket.

Another query -  How to navigate from **login** scene of **auth** to any scene say **mainScene2** ? Is there any special method for that?

Comment: You need to use the syntax `Actions.sceneKey()`, called from whatever button / UI element is used to navigate.

Comment: I got this error "Error: There is no route defined for key employeeList. Must be one of: 'auth','main'"

Comment: Where is your scene with key `employeeList`? You should try `Actions.mainScene2()`

Comment: Actualy mainScene1 was the employeeList inside by project. I changed it to make the my question easy to understand but I forgot to change employeeList to mainScene1. I am updating my question.

Comment: If you navigated from employeeList to employeeEdit and want to go back, then you need to use Actions.pop();